# How to add the service name using env vairables in serverless.yml

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, serverless, serverless-framework

I am trying to set the serverless service name from the env file.

I have written it as

```
service: ${env:SERVICE_NAME}
```

It worked perfectly in previous versions of serverless framework. However since I upgraded it to the latest version, it has started throwing error stating

```
  The stack service name "${env:SERVICE_NAME}-dev" is not valid. A service name should only contain alphanumeric (case sensitive) and hyphens. It should start with an alphabetic character and shouldn't exceed 128 characters.
```

I have tried  setting the service name manually and it works like charm. But the with env variable it stops working.

I have added all the plugins properly and the env variables works on different sections like resources and provider. It just not work in service name.

#serverless.yml

```
service: ${env:SERVICE_NAME}

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-warmup
  - serverless-python-requirements
  - serverless-wsgi
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin
  - serverless-attach-managed-policy
  - serverless-api-gateway-caching
```

Comment: What is your serverless version? The plugin seems to be incompatible with serverless 3.x.x. https://github.com/neverendingqs/serverless-dotenv-plugin/discussions/155.

Comment: My serverless version is 2.72 @RegisterSole

Comment: When deploying, serverless will print the list of env variables. Do you see `SERVICE_NAME`? Like `DOTENV: Loading environment variables from .env:
Serverless:      - SERVICE_NAME`.

Comment: Yeah.... it shows 
Serverless: DOTENV: Loading environment variables from .env:
Serverless:   - SERVICE_NAME

Comment: Ok I'm using sls 2.69, and able to use env in the service name. Question, you mentioned you have written it as `service: ${env:SERVICE_NAME}`, but the error message has `dev` at the end (`${env:SERVICE_NAME}-dev`). Is it possible you are referring to a different serverless.yml? Or that the value inside `.env` file itself is `${env:SERVICE)NAME}-dev`?

Comment: Noo the value inside env is simply a string "teststage". And I have only 1 serverless through which I deploy it. What version of serverless-dotenv-plugin are you using? @RegisterSole

Comment: My `serverless-dotenv-plugin` is `3.12.2`

Comment: I have the same one. Yet it fails for some reason :(

Comment: Sorry my bad, my previous run was incorrect. I tried again, i got the same error with the `-dev` suffix, even though I don't have it in my config.